# Template Namespacing

Tags: templates, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this line on one of my Service Providers:

```
\View::addNamespace('foo', asset('/bar'));
```

But doesn't render on my Blade template using the following line:

```
{{ HTML::image("foo::img.".$image, "Image") }}
```

Instead of rendering the above line, it displays a literal "foo::img.animagesomwwhereinmysite.png". Is there a way I can make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`View::addNamespace` only tells your Service Provider of the particular location where you are storing views; that declaration itself doesn't pass anything along to the view. (See the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-configuration).)

So when you are calling the helper function `{{ HTML::image() }}`, it is expecting, as its first parameter, the URL of the image. In your case, you are specifying the URL as the literal string "foo::img.imagename".

Assuming your images are in the directory `foo/img/`, this should work:

```
{{ HTML::image("foo/img/".$image, "Image") }}
```